# Multiple Lines of text shows after a segment of UISegmentedControl is clicked, but not initially - UPDATED CODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to set multiple lines of text in each segment of a `UISegmentedControl`. 
I tried the following code and it works fine, but the problem is that when the page is loaded for the first time, and the segmented control is shown for the first time, it does not show multiple lines of text, but when i click on one of the segments, the text shows up in multiple line.
How to fix this? Here's the code:

```
    -(void)configureInitialPage
    {
        //Setting up the segmented control
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:trends];
        segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.03 green:0.28 blue:0.51 alpha:1.0];

        for (id segment in [segmentedControl subviews]) {

            for (id label in [segment subviews]) {

                if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

                    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) label;

                    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 97, 50);
                    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];
                    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(20, 510, 720, 40);
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [segmentedControl layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

}
```

Comment: How do you add the control to view? Post the code

Comment: I have called the above method "configureInitialPage" from viewDidLoad of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Do `[segmentedControl layoutIfNeeded]` before adding it as a subview.

Comment: I did this, but only a few segments of the segmented control fit the text. Some do not..!! But when i remove your line of code, then after clicking on any of the segment, all the segments get properly aligned.. why is this happening?

Comment: In my test, I set a frame on the segmented control. Maybe something to try if you haven't already. Also, you should show how the view is added.