# How to resize text (font) to fit in UISegment of UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there any way to reduce font size that can be fit in single segment of `UISegmentedControl` ?

Have tried many thing something like,

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISegmentedControl class], nil] adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth];

[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISegmentedControl class], nil] setMinimumScaleFactor:0.5];
```

AND

```
 NSArray *arr = segment.subviews;  // segment is UISegmentedControl object

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {

    UIView *aSegment = [arr objectAtIndex:i];

    for (UILabel *label in aSegment.subviews) {

        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

            UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)label;

            [myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

            label.numberOfLines = 0;
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
        }



    }
}
```

able to set number of lines of label of segment like,

```
  [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISegmentedControl class], nil] setNumberOfLines:0];
```

Can set single segment size as per content like,

```
  segment.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

but every segment has different size in this case.

I want to keep same size of every segment and want to reduce font size that can be fit in `UISegmentLabel (label)` of `UISegmentedControl` something like `minimumscalefactor` or `minimumfontsize` or `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. These properties is not working for label when contains in `UISegmentedControl`.

If any one can help to achieve this, it will be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453297/scale-uisegmentedcontrol-labels-based-on-width-of-control and see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165171/multiple-lines-of-text-shows-after-a-segment-of-uisegmentedcontrol-is-clicked-b you get some idea

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : thanks for links!! actually i was making little mistake and now solved it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue, Actually it was my mistake!!! I was setting `numberOfLines,adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth,minimumScaleFactor` and `TitleTextAttributes` toghether. If we set `titleTextAttribute` then `minimumScaleFactor` can't work.

**Update :** (As asked by @HawkEye1194 in comment of another answer)

I have end up with below solution,

```
 //this will allow multiple lines in label contained by every segment in segmentedcontroller

[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISegmentedControl class], nil] setNumberOfLines:0];


UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:option];
segment.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, 50);
segment.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segment.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
segment.tag = segmentedControllerBaseTag;


[segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[segment setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName :[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor darkGrayColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[segment setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

If your not setting title textattribute as above then you can use below code

```
// ********** if titletextattributes are not set then below method works ***********

   for(uint i=0;i<[segment subviews].count;i++)
   {
    for(UIView *view in [[[segment subviews] objectAtIndex:i] subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {

            [(UILabel*)view setNumberOfLines:0];
            [(UILabel*)view setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
            [(UILabel*)view setMinimumScaleFactor:0.7];


        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust single segment's size as per it's content by below code,

```
 //*************** adjust single segment size as per content

 segment.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I hope this will help you and you will get an idea how this works-

I have a `UISegmentedControl` i.e. `_userProfileSagmentOutlet` having three segments. Here is sample code-

```
CGFloat fontSize = 15;

[_userProfileSagmentOutlet setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[_userProfileSagmentOutlet setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

this is the previous code which **truncate tail** of title like below image-

[image]

here is the main logic which fit each title in segments with same font size-

```
CGFloat fontSize = 15;

NSAttributedString* firstTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Membership History" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize]}];

NSAttributedString* secondTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Event History" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize]}];

NSAttributedString* thirdTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Booked Classes" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize]}];


float maxW=MAX(MAX(firstTitle.size.width, secondTitle.size.width), thirdTitle.size.width);

while (maxW > _userProfileSagmentOutlet.subviews[0].frame.size.width) {

    fontSize--;

    firstTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Membership History" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize]}];

    secondTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Event History" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize]}];

    thirdTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Booked Classes" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize]}];

    maxW=MAX(MAX(firstTitle.size.width, secondTitle.size.width), thirdTitle.size.width);


}
[_userProfileSagmentOutlet setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[_userProfileSagmentOutlet setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-medium" size:fontSize],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

after using this code image look like this(same font size and text fit to segment and works fine)-

[image]

Here is Swift extension if someone needed-

```
    var fontSize:CGFloat = 15.0;

    var firstTitle = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Membership History", attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)])

    var secondTitle = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Events History" ,attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)]);

    var thirdTitle = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Booked Classes" ,attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)]);

    var maxW:CGFloat = max(max(firstTitle.size().width, secondTitle.size().width), thirdTitle.size().width);

    while (maxW > userProfileSagmentOutlet.subviews[0].frame.size.width) {

        fontSize--;

         firstTitle = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Membership History", attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)])

         secondTitle = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Events History" ,attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)]);

         thirdTitle = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Booked Classes" ,attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)]);

         maxW = max(max(firstTitle.size().width, secondTitle.size().width), thirdTitle.size().width);

    }
    userProfileSagmentOutlet.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

    userProfileSagmentOutlet.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Selected)
```

Comment: this is the good approach but not suitable in my case, because in my cases number of segment(title) is not fix, It is dynamic some time it is 2 where some time it can be 5 or more etc. But your approach is quite good. +1 for that!

Comment: @Lion Thanks..Happy to hear that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4**

allow multiple lines in label

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).numberOfLines = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution in modern Swift would be

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
    _ = Your_UISegmentControl.subviews.compactMap { $0.subviews.compactMap {
        ($0 as? UILabel)?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        ($0 as? UILabel)?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this in the view controller, and called it after viewDidAppear

```
func autoshrinkSegmentFontSize() {
    for subview in segments.subviews {
        for label in subview.subviews {
            if let myLabel = subview as? UILabel {
                myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```