# How to adjust UISegmentedControl font size based on segment width?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl with "n" number of segments. I need to adjust the font size of a segment button title based on a segment width. How to achieve it?

Example Screen:

[image]

TIA!!!

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).minimumScaleFactor = 6.0
        }

Comment: additional help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520242/how-to-resize-text-font-to-fit-in-uisegment-of-uisegmentedcontrol/38524700

Comment: Adjusting font size to fit width isn't correct approach if you have more than 3 segments. Better try to have scrollable segment control

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for that link.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Ya, Maybe that is the correct approach.

Comment: @VimalkumarN.M. May be try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520095/7250862

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
it might help you
segmentedControlName.setWidth(widthvalue, forSegmentAt: segment number you want to change width)

Example segmentedControl.setWidth(150, forSegmentAt: 1)

Comment: segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true

Comment: I don't want to set width. I need to adjust font size based on width.

Comment: @VimalkumarN.M. When you have more than 3 segments and adjust the font size based on width the font will be very smaller and users cant read it